# FireDAC wont allow me to specify network location of firebird database

Tags: delphi, firebird2.5, firedac

FireDAC throws an error when trying to specify a network location of my database. I am using Firebird 2.5 and Delphi XE 5.

Everything works fine until I try using an IP address or network name before the folder location. For example:

```
198.1.1.65:c:\folder\people.GDB
```

I am aware that there is an embedded version of Firebird which uses a certain .dll but I am pretty sure I am using the `fbclient.dll` which should allow this database path.

Comment: Could it be a Professional v. Enterprise feature issue?  In other words, is pointing to a file on a network drive considered to be an Enterprise feature?

Comment: Are you sure this is a FireDAC problem? Can you reach the database with that server address and folder location using a standard client, like FlameRobin? You do have installed FireBird server on that network computer? And that computer does have that database in its C:\folder?

Comment: Even if you were using embedded that wouldn't matter, because the embedded library also works as a client library for external connections. Could you post the exact error message you get when specifying a hostname?

Comment: Im pretty sure its fireDAC, i can connect to the database locally, as soon as I specify an IP address before the database name, I get the error message [FireDAC][Phys][FB]unavailable database. I get the ip address from ipconfig, so again I know that ip address works and i can ping it.  Yes the .GDB file resides in the specified folder.  Like I said the only difference is, I specify the ip address before the database name. My connection string is 'driverid=fb;server=192.168.1.67;database='+text+';user_name=sysdba;password=masterkey'

Comment: text = '192.168.1.67:c:\folder\people.gdb'

Comment: I have the enterprise version of Delphi XE 5.  Is it possible that FireDAC will only allow local connections.. maybe. i will enquire. I cant imagine it would though.

Comment: Infact I have the Architect version of delphi XE 5

Comment: I have XE5 Enterprise and I can connect to local and network firebird databases through FireDAC. The only problem I have had was with having an InterBase XE3 installation on the same computer.

Comment: You do not need the server parameter. I use: DriverID=FB; Database=<servername>:<databasepath>; User_Name=<username>; Password=<password>. And check that the databasepath is valid as interpreted locally by the server. Unless you are using a localhost server, the path is used and validated by the server, not by the client.

Comment: Frazz you little beaut.. yep that was the problem.. I didnt need to use the server parameter .. Fires up like a dream.  How do i give you rep and hugs haha ( its taken days off my life )